# Unexplained space between image and table

Tags: html, css

Good morning!

I have an inexplicable gap between a top image and a generated table on my webpage (www.tradecaptaincoaching.com). The table was generated by http://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables#. After spending the whole day on it, I got the image and the table okay except for the huge 200 pixel gap which is driving me crazy.

I've inspected the page in Chrome and can't see anything strange. Of course, I'm so green that I'm still using tables and have to look up the spelling for "CSS!" ;)

The code is below. Its on a vanilla Drupal Fusion Starter Basic Page. Forgive my bad coding methods. I'm still learning.

Any assistance and learning would be most appreciated!

Thank you everyone.

```
    <img style="padding-top: 20px" alt="Trade Captain Coaching Image" src="/images/LandingImageText.png" style="height:400px; width:960px" usemap="#menumap" />
<map name="menumap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="590,20,650,45" href="http://tradecaptaincoaching.com" alt="Home Page">
  <area shape="rect" coords="675,20,735,45" href="http://tradecaptaincoaching.com/about" alt="About Page">
  <area shape="rect" coords="760,20,830,45" href="http://tradecaptaincoaching.com/contact" alt="Contact Page">
  <area shape="rect" coords="855,20,935,45" href="http://tradecaptaincoaching.com/services" alt="Services Page">
</map>
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:0;margin:0px auto;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;border-style:none;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:5px 20px;border-style:none;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-cfld{font-size:13px;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important;;color:#000064; padding:5px 20px;}
.tg .tg-e9q7{font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important;;background-color:rgb(116,196,218);color:#000064;line-height: 30px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;}
.tg .tg-031e{vertical-align:top;line-height: 20px; padding:5px 0px 23px 0px}
</style>
<table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 960px">
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 320px">
<col style="width: 320px">
<col style="width: 320px">
</colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-e9q7">Choose Your Course</th>
    <th class="tg-e9q7">Your Promotion</th>
    <th class="tg-e9q7">Your Program</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-cfld">Text Here. </td>
    <td class="tg-cfld">Text Here. </td>
    <td class="tg-cfld">Text Here. </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e" rowspan="4"><img src="/images/NoGold.png" style="height:300px; width:320px" /></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><img style="margin:0px auto;display:block" src="/images/ContactUs.png" style="height:30px; width:147px" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-e9q7" colspan="2">Your First Trade Here is FREE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-cfld" colspan="2">Text Here. <br><br><br><br><br><br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of LandingImageText.png?  Is there a 200px white space below the image? Open it up in an image editor and check the dimensions.

Comment: It's 960 by 400. Which is correct. And it looks okay when I inspect the element in Chrome. But then...I'm not so smart so :p

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why is your `style` block in your html `body`?  There is no reason to put it there.  Instead, put it in your `head` block.

Second, in the page you pointed to, you have several `<br>` elements after your `<script>` block.  These alone will add unwanted space between your header image and the table:

```
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Lastly, you are adding even more `<br>` elements inside of your image `map` definition.  There shouldn't be any breaks in there at all.  As breaks don't make sense in that context, they are just added to the visible flow of the page after the image.

Comment: Thank you! The only place in my code that has </br> is in the last line of the last cell. Well after the image. I use them because if I do not all the cell sizings after the gold image do not work and I could not think of any other solution. Looking at the code, I have no </br> in my map section. How are you seeing them and I'm not? Sorry, but I do not know what your first paragraph means. I'd lose the </br> if I knew how to get the same result without them :p

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help and insight. I finally solved it by removing all line breaks in my code. Which makes the code virtually unreadable. But then, CSS is virtually unreadable to me anyway. So what goes around comes around ;) There is still a small break between my top image and table which remains a mystery. But I have an eight hour limit on any one CSS problem and this has well exceeded.

Once again, thanks to all you saints!
CA